# Calling C function that requires sockaddr

Tags: go, cgo

I have a C function that takes a sockaddr pointer.

I've created a syscall.RawSockaddrInet4 object, but I cannot figure out how to cast the address of the object to a C.sockaddr pointer.

I've tried this, (*syscall.RawSockaddr)(unsafe.Pointer(&sa)), but I get an error:

cannot use (*syscall.RawSockaddr)(unsafe.Pointer(&sa)) (type *syscall.RawSockaddr) as type *C.struct_sockaddr in argument to _Cfunc_lib_connect

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

int lib_connect( int sock,
    enum lib_sock_type type,
    const struct sockaddr* srv,
    int srv_sz);

Comment: [github search is your friend](https://github.com/search?q=language%3Ago+struct_sockaddr&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: From the code snippets visible in the link it looks like you should be able to do it like this `(*C.struct_sockaddr)(unsafe.Pointer(&sa))`, although I haven't tested it myself so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks mkopriva!

(*C.struct_sockaddr)(unsafe.Pointer(&sa))